# How to publish data to QuickBook Online using REST or SDK

Tags: quickbooks-online

I am trying to build a near to realtime data push to QuickBook Online using SpringBoot. I am very interested to know the possibilities.

Please refer me some samples or documents covering the alternatives.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: A Google search should yield lots of samples and documentation. I would suggest starting there, and if you get stuck post the code/specific issue you're stuck at.

Comment: All examples requires a human login to get the token. I am looking for app to app connectivity and not finding much result around that.

Comment: Please update your question then to reflect what you're actually looking for. It's definitely possible.